# prove the identity using combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

Question:

prove combinatorically that $$\frac{(2n)!}{(n!2^n)}$$  is an integer.

I've tried to explain that if we have n white flowers and n different colorfull flowers,
ans we need to arrarnge them in a row, so the solution is $(2n)!/n!$...
I don't know what is the condition that I need in order to get the $2^n$...

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The number of ways of arranging $n$ white and $n$ different colourfull flowers is indeed equal to $\binom{2n}{n} \cdot n! = \frac{(2n)!}{n!}$. However, I don't see an easy way to introduce the $2^n$.

To get the desired expression, a different combinatorial model can be used. For instance, consider the number of ways to pair up $2n$ people. This can be done by first arranging the people in a row ($(2n)!$ possibilities) and then choosing the first and second person, the third and fourth, etcetera. We can order the pairs in $n!$ ways and order the people in each pair in $2$ ways, hence we have to divide $(2n)!$ by $n! 2^n$.

Comment: The two models and the derivation of the resulting numbers of arrangements are fine and clear to me. But, I can't see that the division gives an integer. Could you please explain?

Comment: The idea is that since the formula yields the number of ways to make up these pairs, it must be an integer (since there will always be an integer number of ways to pair them up). Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think one aspect is missing in your argumentation. Doubtless, both of your models are proper to solve the question. But at this point, I can only conclude that $n!2^n < (2n)!$ and not that $n!2^n$ is a divisor of $(2n)!$. I will add a short note, to clarify this argument. Regards, Markus

Answer (score 1):

Consider this problem: a mega-spider has $n$ legs.  Under the requirement that for each leg the spider has to put on a sock before putting on a shoe, how many ways can the spider put on $n$ identical socks and $n$ identical shoes?

Comment: Of course equivalent, but I like it!

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add a short remark to the answer already given from [user133281](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/133281/user133281), since I think one argument is missing to completely answer the question. [user133281](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/133281/user133281) provides us with two fine models. The first model places $2n$ people in a row, which can be arranged in $(2n)!$ ways. The second gives us $n$ pairs, which can be arranged in $n!$ ways and within each pair both people can exchange their position, resulting in a factor $2^n$ for each of the $n$ pairs, giving a total of $n!2^n$. Now we have to act carefully. At this point we can only conclude that $$n!2^n<(2n)!$$ and we (additionally) have to argue, that $n!2^n$ divides  $(2n)!$ in order to show that $(2n)!/(n!2^n)$ is an integer. Of course, simple calculation gives the result immediately, since e.g. by using double factorial notation you have $(2n)!=(2n)!!(2n-1)!!=(n!2^n)(2n-1)!!$ showing that $(2n)!$ is an integer multiple of $n!2^n$.

But we should give a combinatorial proof. So, we ask in how many ways can we select $n$ pairs. No significance attaches to the order of the $n$ pairs, nor the order within each pair, since we already know, there are $n!2^n$ different possible arrangements for one specific selection. All that matters now is *who is together and who is apart*. For a person in the first pair there are $2n-1$ different possibilities to complete this pair. For a person in the second pair there are $2n-3$ different possibilities to choose from the remaining people to complete this pair. Proceeding this way gives a total of $(2n-1)(2n-3)\cdot\ldots\cdot3\cdot1=(2n-1)!!$ different possibilities for selecting $n$ pairs. Now we have exhausted *all* possible arrangements of $2n$ people showing, that $(2n)!$ is a multiple of $2^nn!$. And so we can conclude, that $(2n)!/(2^nn!)$ gives an integer. :-)

Comment: Thanks for clearing up my argument. In fact, I also counted the number of ways to select $n$ pairs, but I might have been a bit unclear. The idea is to construct a bijection between the possible sets of pairs and certain orderings of $2n$ people in a row, of which there are $(2n)!/(2^n n!)$.

Comment: That's it! Bijection is the key word ... and I see we share the same ideas! :-)